# iPhone crash for feeding base64 to webview

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, memory-leaks, base64

I am using UIImagePickerController to choose image/video,upon selection I am converting the resource into base64 string and I am sending that to wkwebview

```
NSData(contentsOfURL:(info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL)!)?.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

I am sending the base64 string to webview using *evaluatejavascript*

Here is the JS function

```
function showResource(base64,type){
        if (type == "image"){
            document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML="<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,"+base64+"' width='100' height='100' alt='No Image'/>";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML="<video width='320' height='240' controls><source src='data:video/x-m4v;base64,"+base64+"'></video>";
        }
}.
```

I am facing the following problems

- sometimes the webpage that is in webview becomes blank
- sometimes the application gets crashed
- sometimes the device goes into multiple
  reboot

I couldn't find any memory leak in native code.I tried Instruments.

- try loading a video of 25 seconds long first time it won't crash and you can't find a memory leak in Instruments
- try loading the same video again the results are same
- try doing the same,this time you'll see the device has gone offline

  or if we try to load a video that's 60 longs it will crash the first time itself.

I am not sure what's causing the problem.

As the page is turning blank , it could be a javascript memory leak I thought

[image]

But I don't think the above function can cause memory leak since we're reassigning the new base64 on the same variable the older base64 should have been released from the memory and moreover javascript is garbage collected language.

so this is contradicting.

so base64 conversion might take more memory which in turn causes iOS to crash the app or crash the iPhone also in worst case but if this is the case why sometime html page is turning blank.

so this is also contradicting.

Any help is appreciated !

*Update:*

So far in my research it shows the problem is with memory leak in javascript.

Comment: May I know why I am down voted ?

Comment: converting base64 takes time so convert using async thread and then when its done then assign , this may fix blank page issue

Comment: Ok I will try that.

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari - It doesn't solve the problem.It seems there is a problem with JS memory handling.why the memory keeps on adding instead of getting released

Comment: I tried clearing the cache but that also not helps

Comment: You'd be better off writing the video to disk, and loading that.

Comment: @mattsven - We can't load the video on webview directly unless it's part of the app bundle

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H You can if you use the /tmp directory. https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/WKWebViewTips

Comment: @mattsven - If the web page is local then image or video can be loaded from tmp directory else it won't load.Here is the [link](http://imgur.com/a/VrGee) to error message which I captured from safari remote debugger

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H This isn't clear. Is the web page local (`file:///`) or remote (`http://`, etc.)?

Comment: The web page is remote and resource is in tmp directory.

Answer (score 0):

If xcode print "pointer being freed was not allocated * set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug" ,try to turn off the safari web viewer.