# memory leak in javascript for bigger strings

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, base64, out-of-memory

I am sending base64 string to the javascript function
but its causing memory leak when I call it again and again.
My gut feeling is the value which is stored in javascript variable is not getting released properly.

```
function showResource(data){
//everything commented out.
}
```

I am calling the function from anonymous function that'd be like below The anonymous function is called from iOS native side which sends base64 to webpage

```
function (data){
  showResource(data);
}
```

AFAIK the JS is garbage collected language and so this memory leak problem should not happen but it happens.

When the memory leak happens its getting killed by iOS.Have a look at the screenshot.

[image: Page crash]

This question is related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39161935/730807)

Comment: It can be caused because you pass arguments from "parent" function to another function. I know that it caused an issue in some JS engines (definitely it was impacting performance I'm not sure about memory leaks), try to assign `data` to a new variable inside anonymous function and then pass the reference to `showResource`

Comment: How to pass it as reference ?AFAIk js only supports pass by value.

Comment: JS pas numbers and strings as value but objects as reference. I meant to do something like `function (data){
  var x = data;
  showResource(x);
}`

Comment: This is where I found it (section 3.2): https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments

Comment: If the leak is happening even when showResource is empty, the data may be held up by a closure, which we won't be able to tell unless the full lifecycle of data is provided.  For example if the data is acquired by ajax you need to also make sure the ajax object is not retained.

Comment: @Sheepy - I'm not using ajax.I am sending the base64 to webview using [evaluatejavascript](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/wkwebview/evaluatejavascript-how-to-run-javascript-on-a-wkwebview) method .If its held up ,then how to release it

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H In all modern languages with auto garbage collection, including JS and Swift, memory are released by removing all references to the garbage data.  On Chrome/Firefox/Edge and on Java there are debug tools that let you trace allocated memory and trace the references holding them up.  But how or whether you can do that in Apple's garden is something I can't answer.

Comment: @Sheepy - Apple has a set of tools called **Instruments** to verify it.In iOS we have a in app browser called WebView using which we can load websites and interact with it.The problem is not inside the swift the problem is with javascript  for sure.